# clearInterval does not stop the interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After looking around on the same issue here, I couldn't find a solution for my problem. What I have is the following problem

```js
function movement(mov, element) {
  canvasMov = document.getElementById('xy_canvas');
  ctxMov = canvasMov.getContext("2d");
  wMov = canvasMov.width;
  hMov = canvasMov.height;
  if (element != 'xy_canvas') {
    my_range = document.getElementById(element);
    if (mov) {
      my_interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (my_range != null)
          touchEvents(my_range.value);
        sendMovements(element);
      }, 160);
    } else {
      clearInterval(my_interval);
      console.log(element, mov);
      my_range.value = 0;
    }
    if (my_range.value == 0)
      clearInterval(my_interval);
  } else {
    if (mov) {
      my_interval = setInterval(function() {
        eventsMove();
        sendMovements();
      }, 160);
    } else {
      clearInterval(my_interval);
      console.log(element, mov);
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col12 fl">
  <input type="range" id="alt_range" min="-1" max="1" value="0" step="0.2" class="slider" oninput="movement(true,'alt_range')" onmouseup="movement(false,'alt_range')">
</div>
```

clearInterval doesn't stop the intervalm maybe I'm missing something here, any suggestions please?

Comment: On a related note: get into the habit of declaring your variables with `var` or `let` ASAP - one of these days you'll be pulling your hair because two unrelated functions keep accessing a pesky variable named `x` that bubbled up to the global scope because you wrote `x = something` instead of `var x = something`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start a new interval function you don't stop the old one. `clearInterval(my_interval)` will then only stop the last one that was started, but older ones will keep running. You need to call `clearInterval(my_interval);` before each of the  `setInterval()` calls.

And since all paths through the code eventually call either `setInterval()` or `clearInterval()`, you could just do `clearInterval(my_interval)` once at the beginning of the function.

```js
function movement(mov, element) {
  canvasMov = document.getElementById('xy_canvas');
  ctxMov = canvasMov.getContext("2d");
  wMov = canvasMov.width;
  hMov = canvasMov.height;
  clearInterval(my_interval)
  if (element != 'xy_canvas') {
    my_range = document.getElementById(element);
    if (mov) {
      if (my_range.value != 0) {
        my_interval = setInterval(function() {
          if (my_range != null)
            touchEvents(my_range.value);
          sendMovements(element);
        }, 160);
      }
    } else {
      console.log(element, mov);
      my_range.value = 0;
    }
  } else {
    if (mov) {
      my_interval = setInterval(function() {
        eventsMove();
        sendMovements();
      }, 160);
    } else {
      console.log(element, mov);
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col12 fl">
  <input type="range" id="alt_range" min="-1" max="1" value="0" step="0.2" class="slider" oninput="movement(true,'alt_range')" onmouseup="movement(false,'alt_range')">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, it works! I just needed to add var my_interval = null; before the function, because when you call clearInterval at the begining "my_interval" needs to be defined.

Comment: Of course, if you're using a global variable you should declare and initialize it outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is define `my_interval` at the top, something like

```
var my_interval = null;
```

At the moment, you are creating `my_interval` in your `if` condition, it is hidden for the rest of the code.

Comment: That is unlikely to be the problem. When `var` is not used, the variable will go up in the scope, in this case eventually hitting `window` (in other words, in the question `my_interval = something` is the same as `window.my_interval = something`).  -- Also, `if`s don't create scopes for `var`s in JavaScript, functions do. (In the new ES6 `let` and `const`, then, yes, `{}`s create scopes.)

Comment: @acdcjunior I see, but then the code should work clearing the interval. :-S

Comment: Yeah, I think so too :D There's probably something else. Maybe those `if`s aren't being executed, I don't know...